# How to add user to a group from terminal on Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, user-accounts

When I run

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh GroupMembership $USERNAME
```

I get

```
append: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at my copy of Mountain Lion and the com.apple.access_ssh group doesn't exist until you've actually turned on "Remote Login" in System Preferences.

When you turn on Remote Desktop AND set it to "Allow access for: Only these users", then there is a group called "com.apple.access_ssh". When you set it back to ""Allow access for: All users", the name of the group is changed to "com.apple.access_ssh-disabled".

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how you can add groups to your SSH access list (aka a [SACL](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-sacl-permissions-in-lion-server.html)). All commands must be run with root privileges:

Command to create the SACL (if it doesn’t already exist):

```
dseditgroup -o create -q com.apple.access_ssh
```

Add your group as a nested group inside the SACL group:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -a group_name_here -t group com.apple.access_ssh
```

If you’re adding an AD group, you may need to add the AD domain’s name:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -a DOMAIN\group_name_here -t group com.apple.access_ssh
```

Comment: After trying so many different things, including using the `kickstart` utility, this finally fixed the problem I had in which the connection was successful, login was successful, but then the connection was immediately closed with "`PAM: user account has expired for ...`" - so thank you, I hope this helps others with the same problem.